# React - Css/Scss File can't be import in my jsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

[image: import error]
[image: files location]
[image: errors showed in browser]
[image: Scss file]

I couldn't manage to import my CSS file even though I already download the required node modules.

Also I change and try module

I tried to import the CSS file in my React component, though the existing CSS/SCSS file is not working when I import it.

Comment: maybe the ts compiler removes the import because for him it's never used? have you tried accessing `styles` (idk by putting it inside a variable) and then test it? also does it change something if you remove the `.module.` in the import?

Comment: `CardBorder.scss` should be named `CardBorder.module.css`, this would make it accurate to the actual import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I recently updated my machine using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

, which for some reason seems to have broken the links to `/CardBorder.scss` in the root file path(/).

I ran sudo update-grub, which fixed that issue. Afterwards, I noticed that quickly before it (still) couldn't find `/CardBorder.scss`, it would flash an error saying it couldn't find axios.

I ran `npm install axios`.

everything works now. Not sure which one fixed it, but hopefully this saves somebody else a 4 day headache!

Comment: yes you were right it wasn't a solution now i found the solution :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you're trying to do, even if the blog is about tailwind.

```
// Navigation.styles.js
export default {
  nav: 'container',
  ul: [
    'flex',
    'flex-col',
    'justify-end',
    'list-none',
    'sm:flex-row',
  ].join(' '),
  li: [
    'mb-3',
    'sm:ml-3',
    'sm:mb-0',
    'even:bg-gray-50',
    'odd:bg-white',
  ].join(' '),
  a: ({ isActive }) =>
    [
      'text-black',
      'font-bold',
      'inline-block',
      'rounded-full',
      'bg-yellow-400',
      'py-1',
      'px-3',
      isActive ? 'text-white' : 'hover:bg-yellow-500',
    ].join(' '),
}
```

Usage:

```
// Navigation.jsx
import styles from "./Navigation.styles";

const Navigation = ({ links }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  return (
    <nav className={styles.nav}>
      <ul className={styles.ul}>
        {links.map((link, index) => {
          const isActive = router.pathname === link.path
          return (
            <li key={index} className={styles.li}>
              <a className={styles.a({ isActive })} href={link.path}>
                {link.name}
              </a>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Source: [Simple strategy for structuring classnames](https://dev.to/wheelmaker24/a-simple-strategy-for-structuring-tailwindcss-classnames-1ba9)

Comment: nope mate but thanks i just added some photograph for more information  :D